# Sticky buttons to the edge of the browser

Tags: button, fluid, sticky

I am looking to create a situation where some nav buttons are sticky to the edge of the browser windows,  I am assuming some css and javascript,  it has been a long time since I did any coding and I am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/66009984@N00/6824355131/

Answer (score 0):

Make the buttons position absolute or static depending on if you want them to scroll with the page or not.

```
.buttonLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0
}

.buttonRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0
}
```

If you want them inside another div than that parent div needs to have it's position set relative.

```
.parentContainer { position: relative }
```